# String value printed as int in laravel blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Good Day.
I'm looking for help regarding my issue
I pass an array holding all photos from controller to blade view. one of the values printed as an integer although it is saved id the database as a string

[image: this is the value in database]

this is my controller

```
public function myServices()
{
    $hallArray =  Auth::user()->servproviders->hallservices->all();
    return view('providers.subservices.myservices')->with('hallArray',$hallArray);
}
```

this is the blade.php

[image: this is the blade.php]

```
@foreach (array_reverse($hallArray) as $hall)
                <div class="thumb">
                <p> {{$halls->s_ID}}</p>
@endforeach
```

this is the output

[image: this is the output]

it prints only the numbers at the beginning not all the value, although all other values are printed correctly

any advice, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use laravel Eloquent Attribute Casting.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        's_ID' => 'string',
    ];
}
```